# How can I optimize filtering function

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, nestjs, filtering

I'm working on angular, nestjs, graphql and mongodb. So I have a modal component  for filtering data that contains multi field. I wrote this code but I'm sure that's not a good practice and there is anther way to achieve same target.
In order to learn how to write clean code I hope one of the heros could help me

I tried this attempt but I don't think it's good

`

```
 let matchingValue: any;
    let matchingValuePipeline: any;
    // const { bySn, byBank, byClient, byModel, byRegion, bySite, byTerminalId } =
    //   search;
    for (let item in search) {
      if (search[item] === '') {
        matchingValue = { inUse: true };
        matchingValuePipeline = { bindedSuperAdmin: name };
      }
    }
    //-----------------------------
    if (search.byBank) {
      matchingValuePipeline = { bindedBanque: search.byBank };
    }
    if (search.byBank && search.byClient) {
      matchingValuePipeline = {
        bindedBanque: search.byBank,
        bindedClient: search.byClient,
      };
    }
    if (search.byBank && search.byClient && search.bySite) {
      matchingValuePipeline = {
        bindedBanque: search.byBank,
        bindedClient: search.byClient,
        nameUser: search.bySite,
      };
    }
    if (search.byBank && search.byClient && search.bySite && search.byModel) {
      matchingValuePipeline = {
        bindedBanque: search.byBank,
        bindedClient: search.byClient,
        nameUser: search.bySite,
      };
      matchingValue = { inUse: true, model: search.byModel };
    }
    if (
      search.byBank &&
      search.byClient &&
      search.bySite &&
      search.byModel &&
      search.byRegion
    ) {
      matchingValuePipeline = {
        bindedBanque: search.byBank,
        bindedClient: search.byClient,
        nameUser: search.bySite,
        region: search.byRegion,
      };
      matchingValue = { inUse: true, model: search.byModel };
    }
    if (
      search.byBank &&
      search.byClient &&
      search.bySite &&
      search.byModel &&
      search.byRegion &&
      search.bySn
    ) {
      matchingValuePipeline = {
        bindedBanque: search.byBank,
        bindedClient: search.byClient,
        nameUser: search.bySite,
        region: search.byRegion,
      };
      matchingValue = { inUse: true, model: search.byModel, sn: search.bySn };
    }
    if (
      search.byBank &&
      search.byClient &&
      search.bySite &&
      search.byModel &&
      search.byRegion &&
      search.bySn &&
      search.byTerminalId
    ) {
      matchingValuePipeline = {
        bindedBanque: search.byBank,
        bindedClient: search.byClient,
        nameUser: search.bySite,
        region: search.byRegion,
      };
      matchingValue = {
        inUse: true,
        model: search.byModel,
        sn: search.bySn,
        terminalId: search.byTerminalId,
      };
    }

    if (search.byClient) {
      matchingValuePipeline = { bindedClient: search.byClient };
    }
    if (search.bySite) {
      matchingValuePipeline = { nameUser: search.bySite };
    }
    if (search.byRegion) {
      matchingValuePipeline = { region: search.byRegion };
    }
    if (search.bySn) {
      matchingValue = { sn: search.bySn };
    }
    if (search.byModel) {
      matchingValue = { model: search.byModel };
    }
    if (search.byTerminalId) {
      matchingValue = { terminalId: search.byTerminalId };
    }

    //--------------------------------------
    // for testing purpose
    console.log('matchingValue', matchingValue);
    console.log('matchingValuePipeline', matchingValuePipeline);
    console.log('search', search);

    let filter;
    if (role === ROLEV1.MS_TECH_SOFT) {
      filter = await this.modelTpe.aggregate([
        {
          $match: matchingValue,
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'profiles',
            localField: 'merchantName',
            foreignField: 'nameUser',
            as: 'listTpe',
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: matchingValuePipeline,
              },
            ],
          },
        },
```

`

**search** defined like this as DTO

```
@InputType()
export class SearchMethods {
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  bindedBanque?: string;
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  bindedClient?: string;
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  nameUser?: string;
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  region?: string;
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  model?: string;
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  sn: string;
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  terminalId?: string;
}
```

To achieve all conditions I will write at least 100 line

Comment: Hey Maryem! where is `search` defined? can you please also include that part or at least a mock of it?

Comment: it's dto im going to update my post check it

Answer (score 0):

You can add attributes to an object, e.g. like this

```
let matchingValue = {};
if (search.byBank) matchingValue.bindedBanque = search.byBank;
if (search.byClient) matchingValue.bindedClient = search.byClient;
if (search.bySite) matchingValue.nameUser = search.bySite;
matchingValue.nameUser = {$in: [a, b]}

modelTpe.aggregate([
   { $match: matchingValue }
])
```

Instead of `matchingValuePipeline.bindedBanque` you can write `matchingValuePipeline["bindedBanque"]`, where `"bindedBanque"` can also be a variable.

You can also remove keys:

```
delete matchingValue.bindedBanque;
```

There is no need to have dedicated case for each combination.